# Ajax Call to Monorail Controller JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, castle-windsor, castle-monorail

I could really use an example of this. Can anyone provide me with a sample implementation of a Javascript function using JQuery (not totally necessary) to make a Castle Monorail call?

I have Monorail configured to intercept all HttpRequests with "*.ashx". Using an Ajax call I would like to pass a parameter to my Monorail Controller and get back a string.

Can someone give me some pseudo code or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just want to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/my/controller', { testParam: "testValue"}, function(data) {
        alert('The controller returned ' + data);
    });
});
```

See http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax